# multiple elements toggle second click remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having difficulty with jQuery.
Basically I would like the first click on "div 1" the others have a class and the text "lorem ipsum" appears and so on with the others. But if I re-click on the same the class would be removed showing them without class.

I hope I have been clear, thank you

```js
 $(function() {
   $('.showSingle a').click(function() {
     $('.targetDiv').not('#div' + $(this).attr('data-target')).hide();
     $('#div' + $(this).attr('data-target')).toggle();
     $('.showSingle a').not('#color' + $(this).attr('data-target')).addClass('filteropacity')
     $('#color' + $(this).attr('data-target')).removeClass('filteropacity');
   });
 });
```

```css
.filteropacity {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showSingle">
  <a class="link1" id="color1" data-target="1">Div 1</a>
  <a class="link2" id="color2" data-target="2">Div 2</a>
  <a class="link3" id="color3" data-target="3">Div 3</a>
  <a class="link4" id="color4" data-target="4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

Comment: Change ````$('#div' + $(this).attr('data-target')).toggle();```` to ````$('#div' + $(this).attr('data-target')).show();````. The toggle() method toggles between hide() and show() for the selected elements.

Comment: @Alex But in this way I can no longer close everything and return to the initial state

Comment: You are right. So how would you like to return to the initial state ?

Comment: @alex Now it works like this: first click above "Div 1" the text appears to me, and on the other clicks the class is applied. If I click another time over "div 1" I would like the class to be removed is it possible?

Comment: @alex Basically the opposite of this: when I click over Div 1 I would like the others to turn red then when I click the second time the same they all turn black https://codepen.io/documarketing/pen/dyQVZPZ

Comment: @KiranShahi Hi, your answer is great but if I had a structure where I cannot use "siblings" like this how can I proceed? Thanks for the help codepen.io/bastia-g5/pen/RwqLdzO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea for the solution to your problem is, you need to track the clicked element and need to add your business logic based on the tracked element. For instance, in my solution, I have added an active class to the clicked item if the content is shown and removed the active class if the content is hidden. And I have checked the active class when the user clicks on it. If there is an active class that already exists then we need to remove it and also need to remove the `filteropacity` of its siblings. See the following example for a sample.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.showSingle a').off("click").on("click", function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('filteropacity');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("active").removeClass("filteropacity");
      $(this).siblings().addClass('filteropacity');
    }


    $('.targetDiv').not('#div' + $(this).attr('data-target')).hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('data-target')).toggle();
    //$('.showSingle a').not('#color' + $(this).attr('data-target')).addClass('filteropacity')
    //$('#color' + $(this).attr('data-target')).removeClass('filteropacity');
  });
});
```

```css
.filteropacity {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showSingle">
  <a class="link1" id="color1" data-target="1">Div 1</a>
  <a class="link2" id="color2" data-target="2">Div 2</a>
  <a class="link3" id="color3" data-target="3">Div 3</a>
  <a class="link4" id="color4" data-target="4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

As per the code you provide in your codepen (https://codepen.io/bastia-g5/pen/RwqLdzO) I have updated it with the following code. In this code, I have stored the parent i.e., of the clicked element `<div id="boh" class="showSingle">` and played with its siblings.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.showSingle a').off("click").on("click", function() {
    $parentElement = $(this).closest(".showSingle");
    $parentElement.siblings(".showSingle").removeClass("active");
    if ($parentElement.hasClass("active")) {
      $parentElement.removeClass("active");
      $parentElement.siblings(".showSingle").removeClass('filteropacity');
    } else {
      $parentElement.addClass("active").removeClass("filteropacity");
      $parentElement.siblings(".showSingle").addClass('filteropacity');
    }


    $('.targetDiv').not('#div' + $(this).attr('data-target')).hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('data-target')).toggle();
  });

});
```

```css
.filteropacity {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boh" class="showSingle">
  <a class="link1" id="color1" data-target="1">Div 1</a>
</div>
<div id="boh" class="showSingle">
  <a class="link2" id="color2" data-target="2">Div 2</a>
</div>
<div id="boh" class="showSingle">
  <a class="link3" id="color3" data-target="3">Div 3</a>
</div>
<div id="boh" class="showSingle">
  <a class="link4" id="color4" data-target="4">Div 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv" style="display:none;">Lorum Ipsum4</div>
```

Comment: Hi, your answer is great but if I had a structure where I cannot use "siblings" like this how can I proceed? Thanks for the help codepen.io/bastia-g5/pen/RwqLdzO

Comment: @bastiag5 I have updated my answer with a new code based on the code you provided in Codepen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however the class is also applied to the targetDiv div while I would like it to apply only to the showSingle class

Comment: @bastiag5 that easy mate. Just pass `.showSingle` class inside `siblings()` function like `siblings(".showSingle")`. check the updated answer. :)

Comment: Thank you for your patience, with your code I figured out how to do it and solved the problem. =)